# No permission to modify static procedure `findall/3' when running a file instead of running interactively

Tags: prolog

I do have some 'database' in .pl file:

```
exotic(1, 1).
exotic(2, 1).
exotic(3, 1).
exotic(4, 1).
exotic(5, 0).
exotic(6, 0).
```

I am running interactively (from terminal after loading the file):

```
findall(X, exotic(X,1), L).
```

It works, L is filled with [1,2,3,4], as expected.

But when I am putting this *findall* in file and I am running a file, I am getting the error: "No permission to modify static procedure `findall/3'".

What does cause it and how to place it in file to have an access to list L?

Comment: Yes, it is true, that I am pretty new to Prolog. But if it was a syntax error, it wouldn't  run from command line, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make a query from a source file, the standard solution is to use an `initialization/1` directive. For example:

```
:- initialization((
    findall(X, exotic(X,1), L),
    write(L), nl
)).
```

You cannot simply write in your source file a **clause** such as:

```
findall(X, exotic(X,1), L).
```

as that would mean (attempting) to redefine a standard built-in predicate, which most Prolog systems don't allow, hence the error you got.

Comment: That is, what I wanted to do. Thank you!